# Post videoclip on the user’s Facebook timeline

Tags: facebook, post, video, facebook-timeline

We have developed an app that creates a videoclip by incorporating the images that a user uploads to our server.
We would like to post the resulting videoclip on the user’s Facebook timeline as soon as the video is ready, i.e. about 30 min after the user has uploaded their images on our server, this means that the post of the resulting videoclip is asynchronous with respect to the session of the user on their mobile device (when they upload their pictures). 
Therefore the posting of the videoclip on the user’s timeline has to come from a a server component using a permanent access token. Pls note that our FB app already has the writing permission on the user's timeline .

Our issue is that when we try to post the video clip on user’s timeline with a curl call by using an access token of the app we get the following error :
  { " error" : { " message": " ( # 200 ) This app is not allowed to publish to other users ' timelines . " , "type " : " OAuthException " , "code " : 200 } }

Can you please let us know how we can avoid this error and get the videoclip on the user’s timeline?

I add some clarifications:

1. The process is asynchronous. It can take 30 minutes, but more than one hour and the user tokens can expire
2. Using long lived access token I can work on the user's timeline, when user is not connected? generation of access token is only by Mobile FB lib (Android and IOS)

the user access token generated by the mobile SDK, should be long lived, but I understand that long-lived access token can not be used if the user is offline ... is that correct?

thanks

Comment: The access token validity is affected by many factors. However, it's not necessarily affected by the user online status. You got two options, 1) when the user use your service, you should make the option to "share to facebook" clear that it will post to their timeline when the video is ready. or 2) once the video is ready, you send a notification to the user and incentivize them to publish it to facebook.
You should be using user access token in both cases.

Comment: Or even better, with the second approach you could use the [share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) where the user can share a OG URL of the video, this way you don't even need the publish_stream permission and you remove a lot of friction.